# Spring Roo do not understand the project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

My project using Spring Roo to create entity, config v.v... six month ago. Everything work ok. But now, when i use Spring Roo to create new entity

```
entity jpa --class example
```

I get the error

```
Command 'entity jpa --class example' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
```

I tried with other command

```
datbase property list
enum constant --name example
```

I get similar error

When I try create an example Roo project and test these command. They work properly

When I try create an empty directory and run command ( not run project --topLevelPackage)

```
entity jpa --class example
```

I get the result

```
Command 'entity jpa --class example' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
```

The Roo version is

```
1.2.5.RELEASE [rev 8341dc2]
```

the content of log.roo file is

```
// Spring Roo 1.2.5.RELEASE [rev 8341dc2] log opened at 2014-04-25 11:01:12
hint
exit
// Spring Roo 1.2.5.RELEASE [rev 8341dc2] log closed at 2014-04-25 11:03:28
// Spring Roo 1.2.5.RELEASE [rev 8341dc2] log opened at 2014-04-25 11:03:35
exit
// Spring Roo 1.2.5.RELEASE [rev 8341dc2] log closed at 2014-04-25 11:04:11
// Spring Roo 1.2.5.RELEASE [rev 8341dc2] log opened at 2014-10-06 09:22:27
version
```

I am not sure but i think the problem because i change something in pom.xml file 
How to solve this problem ? 
Thank for any help.

Comment: Note if Roo examples worked, it seems the problem is in your project ... in that case the info you provided is not sufficient to be able to infer what happens.

Comment: thank @eruiz. I added some missing tag to pom.xml file and fixed the bug

Answer (score 2):

Roo is extremely opinionated and, unlike projects such as Spring Boot, gets unhappy if you disagree with it. Changing any number of configuration settings, such as the location of your `persistence.xml` (or especially not using one) or perfectly valid POM changes, will break Roo in non-obvious ways.

You made some change that makes Roo not realize your project is a JPA project. Compare a clean Roo project to see what's different.

I personally abandoned Roo and have switched to Groovy for virtually everything Roo did, usually using `@CompileStatic` on entity classes.

Comment: Thank @chrylis, I added some missing tag <version> to pom.xml file and now roo can work properly

Comment: @chrylis both Boot and Roo need metainformation to work ... you cannot expect Boot works if you use unsupported annotations in the same way you cannot expect Roo works if you use unsupported annotations.

Moreover Roo uses XML configuration as metainformation too so unsupported info at XML metainf files causes Roo doesn't work as expected. In that behaviour Boot is different to Roo because it doesn't use XML files as metainf.

Comment: @eruiz Boot goes to great lengths to avoid needing metainfo. It uses SPI to enable whatever's on the classpath and `@Conditional` to enable whatever is configured. Roo uses buggy POM parsing and brittle assumptions about where configuration information is stored and can't be told to "trust me, this is a JPA project" if the provider is configured by anything besides a properties file.

Comment: @chrylis anyway Roo and Boot cannot be compared, because Roo is a development tool whereas Boot is a framework, it isn't the same.